# NoSuchElementException when reading p12 file in java application from system?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

In my spring MVC java application, I have a method:

```
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey( String password, InputStream privateKeyFileStream) {
    KeyStore ks;
    Key key = null;
    try {
      ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      ks.load(privateKeyFileStream, password.toCharArray());

      Enumeration<String> enumeration = ks.aliases();

      // uses the default alias
      String keyAlias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();

      key = ks.getKey(keyAlias, password.toCharArray());
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
      ErrorLog.Log(ErrorLog.FATAL, "Error creating WebService. Failed to read private key", e, "WebService", "constructor");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      ErrorLog.Log(ErrorLog.FATAL, "Error creating WebService. Failed to read private key", e, "WebService", "constructor");
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
      ErrorLog.Log(ErrorLog.FATAL, "Error creating WebService. Failed to read private key", e, "WebService", "constructor");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      ErrorLog.Log(ErrorLog.FATAL, "Error creating WebService. Failed to read private key", e, "WebService", "constructor");
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
      ErrorLog.Log(ErrorLog.FATAL, "Error creating WebService. Failed to read private key", e, "WebService", "constructor");
    }

    return (PrivateKey) key;
  }
```

When I utilize this method in my application locally, like so:

```
File file = new File("../bin/file.p12");
InputStream privateKeyFileStream = null;
try {
  privateKeyFileStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
  ErrorLog.Log(ErrorLog.FATAL, "Error creating WebService.", e, "WebService", "constructor");
}
PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey("password", privateKeyFileStream);
```

everything works fine. The p12 file is located in my the bin directory of my tomcat folder.

However, for my testing environment, I place the same p12 file in the same bin folder in the tomcat directory, and when trying to read the file I get the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyEnumeration.nextElement(Collections.java:3083)
    at com.class.util.class.Class.getPrivateKey(ClassUtils.java:92)
    at com.class.util.class.Class.getInstance(Class.java:77)
    at
```

The line of code thats throwing the error is:

```
String keyAlias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
```

It's basically failing to find any certificate entries on the p12 file, yet when I run

```
keytool -list -keystore file.p12 -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -v
```

both on my local system, and the testing environment location, it shows:

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: test
Creation date: Feb 11, 2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
```

What seems to be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead decided to read the p12 file from the resources directory in the application which worked fine.